# canon printer gm2000 how connect to Ubuntu 23.10 arm64

Tags: printing, canon, 23.10, arm64, pixma

I need help connect cannon to Ubuntu 23.10 arm64. I tried different methods, but all in vain. maybe somebody can help me.

i tried different libs but i dont fine right driver

Comment: Does the printer show up in printer settings?